# Azure Logic App Workflow Definition Language to document (markdown) like javadoc

Tags: json, markdown, azure-logic-apps, javadoc

It seems everything‘s already in place. Any logic app has a json code following the Azure Worfklow Definition Language schema (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language.md). What I‘d like to extract is a markdown file containing a customizable amount of information of contained elements of the logic app that is useful as a documentation.

Like javadoc but for Azure WDL.

If nothing like this exists already, I‘d like to create a json to markdown converter myself, but have no clue where to start. Any suggestions?

I found something called WDLDOC but it‘s a different solution. PlantUML could visualize the JSONs but I want to have markdown as result showing entrypoints of the logic app and its comments in a fashionable way.

Cheers
Frank